# Windows powershell environment variable in react-native .env file?

Tags: javascript, react-native, powershell, environment-variables, .env

I want to use the currently given local IP address inside a React Native project.

For this reason, I created a Powershell script file that finds and save the IP Address to the system variable `$env:IPADDR`.

```
Write-Host "Getting current IP Address"
$env:IPADDR = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | where {$_.DHCPEnabled -ne $null -and $_.DefaultIPGateway -ne $null}).IPAddress | Select-Object -First 1
Write-Host "    ---->" $env:IPADDR
```

[image]

Now I want to pass this variable inside my project's `.env` file.

While the `$npm_package_name` works fine, the `$env:IPADDR` does not seem to work. Instead of evaluating the previously defined environmental variable, the output result is the variable literal text itself ie `console.log(REACT_APP_API_URL) --> http://$env:IPADDR:3000/` instead of the evaluated result `http://192.168.10.4:3000/`.

My `.env` file is created like this.

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://$env:IPADDR:3000/
REACT_APP_NAME=$npm_package_name
```

So, where am I doing wrong here? How can I dynamically evaluate the `REACT_APP_API_URL` using the PowerShell environmental variable `$env:IPADDR`?

Comment: Whatever component is evaluating your `.env` file would have to understand PowerShell's `$env:` syntax - which seems unlikely. Does the file format support referencing _other_ environment variables in principle? If so, the likely format is `${IPADDR}` or `$IPADDR` or, for software with Windows heritage, `%IPADDR%`. If `$npm_package_name` works, and `npm_package_name` is also the name of an _environment_ variable (as opposed to a PowerShell _shell-only_ variable), it sounds like it's the former.

Comment: Also note that, by PowerShell's string-expansion rules, `"http://$env:IPADDR:3000/"` would _not_ work as intended; it would have to be `"http://${env:IPADDR}:3000/"`

Comment: @mklement0 The curly braces didn't work either. I tried all the documented possible forms before I post the question.

Comment: Understood. That leaves the mystery of why `$npm_package_name` worked. Incidentally, where is the format documented?

Comment: @mklement0 It seems a second step is needed to expand the system variables with the help of dotenv-expand. You can find the info you want at https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Answer (score 1):

I found no way to expand Windows environmental variables natively inside `.env` file. Instead, I extended the PowerShell script, to "replace" the desired variable by working directly inside the `.env` file.

Here is the final `run.ps1` *PowerShell* script file.

```bash
#Find local IP addr and save it to $env:IPADDR variable
Write-Host "Getting current IP Address"
$env:IPADDR = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | where {$_.DHCPEnabled -ne $null -and $_.DefaultIPGateway -ne $null}).IPAddress | Select-Object -First 1
Write-Host "    ---->" $env:IPADDR

#Replace the value of the key [REACT_APP_API_URL] with the new server ie http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000/
$regex = '(?<=REACT_APP_API_URL=)[^=]*'
$file = '.env'
$addr = 'http://' + $env:IPADDR + ':3000/'
(Get-Content $file) -replace $regex, $addr | Set-Content $file

#Start NPM script
npm run start
```